# Necessity of navigation properties in EF Core models

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

Let's say in our project we use C# and MsSQL and we have one `Products` table with two columns (`ID`,`Name`)

One day we decided to save product information given by `Company1`, so we created a new table `ProductInfoFromCompany1` because it has custom columns (`ProductID`, `Price`, `CurrentScore`)

The next day, we agreed with `Company2` and now we need to save their data as well. So, new table -> `ProductInfoFromCompany2` with different columns (`ProductID`, `Year`, `Rating`)

Another day, we agreed with `Company3` and so on...

So, we have no idea how the data given by new companies will look like. That's why we need to create a new table because if we use one `Details` table, it will be too wide with numerous null columns

In Entity Framework Core we have these models:

```
public class ProductInfoFromCompany1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public double CurrentScore { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInfoFromCompany2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double Rating { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Do we need these navigation properties in this class?
    //public ProductInfoFromCompany1 ProductInfoFromCompany1 { get; set; } 
    //public ProductInfoFromCompany2 ProductInfoFromCompany2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can see my question is commented in the `Product` class.

Do we need to add navigation properties in the `Product` class?

The reason why I'm asking is that in all books or documentation which I've read, people use navigation property, but in this case, it violates open-closed principle because whenever we add new company, we need to modify `Product` class as well.

P.S. if we want to query `ProductInfoFromCompany1` data and we have product `Id`, we can simply start querying from `ProductInfoFromCompany1`, like this

```
var info = _db.ProductInfoesFromCompany1.Where(c=>c.ProductId == productId);
```

Comment: I would suggest you think about another way of designing your DB.
Imagine in 1 year from now you are dealing with 100 companies.This will lead to the creation of 100 tables serving the same purpose without mentioning the mess when querying , and maintaining the code.

Comment: @AdamChawki agree, but now it isn't possible to change the structure

Comment: @JackSparrow OCP has nothing to do with how your *data* looks. Does your `Product` entity have two *different types* of product information? Or does it have a list of the same kind of product information produced by different companies? It looks like the classes are misnamed and `Product` should have a `Rating` and a `Pricing` property. Whether those classes need `Product` and `ProductID` is another matter. Most likely they do

Comment: This question is a blessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do we need to add navigation properties in the `Product` class?

You are the only one who can answer the question if *you need* something or not.

If the question is *does EF Core* require navigation properties, the answer is no. Reference: [Relationships - Single Navigation Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#single-navigation-property) EF Core documentation topic:

> Including just one navigation property (no inverse navigation, and no foreign key property) is enough to have a relationship defined by convention.

In fact EF Core fluent API and shadow properties allow defining relationship without any navigation or FK property. How useful it would be is another story. The main point (which is the question as I read it) is that none of them is mandatory.

Of course the lack of a navigation property imposes some limitations on the type of LINQ queries you can create - like you said, you can't start a query from `Product` and apply filter on associated `ProductInfoFromCompany1`, or eager/explicit/lazy load it.

But if you don't need all that, e.g. as you said, you can build your queries starting from `ProductInfoFromCompany1`, then omitting the navigation property in `Product` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment a design change is required to achieve what you want.
Here is my suggestion:

Since your issue is with the structure of the product table because you don't know what each company wants to store as info for their product you can do it this way : (I ll explain later).

```
 public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Created date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Prodcuts { get; set; }

    }

    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Name")]
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Created date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Company")]
        [Display(Name = "Company")]
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProductField> Fields { get; set; }

    }

    public class ProductField
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Value")]
        [Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        [Display(Name = "Product")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Field")]
        [Display(Name = "Field")]
        public int FieldID { get; set; }
        public virtual Field Field { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Created date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }


public class Field
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        [Index("ActiveAndUnique", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Created date")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Explanation of the code:

This approach gives you more control over your data without having to create a table for each product info.

**Company:**
I started by creating a company table with a navigation property that will lazy load all the products related to it.(if lazy loading is enabled)
Then In the product table I added a FK to reference the company.

**Field:**
Since you mentioned that you don't know what a company will have as product info , you can create a new field and link it to a product using the ProductField table .

**ProductField:** 
This table will act as a "Many to Many" between your product, and field as a result you can add as many field to a new product without having to modify the structure of your product table or create a new one . You can also reuse the same field if company number 3 needs it.

**USAGE:**

Given we have a company named **MyCompany**.
MyCompany has a product named Car and the info required to be added to the car is Make, and Color.
We create two new fields called Make, and Color, then in the ProductField Table we add two new entries: 
The first one will have: 
The ID of the field "Make", The value "BMW", and a reference to the product with its id which is Car.
We do the same thing for color by referencing the the field "Color" and the product "Car".

**Querying:** 
Now querying is simpler than having a table for each company product info.

Example:

```
var myProducts = _db.Products.Where(p=>p.CompanyID== "1").Include(p=>p.Fields).Tolist()
```

Again that's my take on it. Hope it helps.